# Is it possible to load tumblr posts via AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, tumblr

I would simply like to know if it is possible to load tumblr posts via AJAX. I know it's possible with notes but I would like to load posts' content inline. (I'm not talking about infinitescroll)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
I have written some code to read the title of the posts and create a menu on my site.

You can have access to the whole contents of the posts.

Here is a [link to an article explaining](http://dominique-colombani.fr/domblog/index.php?post/2012/03/25/Comment-cr%C3%A9er-un-menu-sur-son-site-avec-les-titres-de-son-blog-tumblr) how to do this.
They are few explanations (in French) and the code of the function, which is quite simple.
If you think that the code is not enough to understand, I can try to write the explanation in english.

Edit : I translate the article in english here : [How to use Tumblr titles to create a menu on your website ?](http://dominique-colombani.fr/domblog/index.php?post/2012/04/11/How-to-use-Tumblr-titles-to-create-a-menu-on-your-website)

Comment: Well... Ce n'est pas vraiment la peine car je parle français lol! ;-) But it's a bit unfair for others seeking for this solution and don't speak french. I guess it's up to you. Thanks for link.